# Unity Inputs cant find my Actions when referencing them in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create an interaction system in Unity using Natty Creations tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPPGnpV1Y1c&t=866s

Although I am having a bit of trouble as the script cant find the Action that I am trying to reference.

I am still a beginner so sorry if this is a stupid question with a simple fix.
Here is the script that I am stuck with:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerInteract : MonoBehaviour
{

private Camera cam;
[SerializeField]
private float distance = 3f;
[SerializeField]
private LayerMask mask;
private PlayerUI playerUI;
private InputManager inputManager;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    cam = GetComponent<PlayerLook>().cam;
    playerUI = GetComponent<PlayerUI>();
    inputManager = GetComponent<InputManager>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    playerUI.UpdateText(string.Empty);
    Ray ray = new Ray(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward);
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * distance);
    RaycastHit hitInfo; // var to store collision info
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, distance, mask))
    {
        if (hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Interactible>() != null)
        {
            Interactible interactible = hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Interactible>();
            playerUI.UpdateText(interactible.promptMessage);
            if (inputManager.OnFoot.Interact.triggered) 
            {
                interactible.BaseInteract();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Input Actions: [Unity Input Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lriVY.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled the `Generate C# class` option ?

Comment: Yes, I generated the C# class for the Input actions.

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Player\PlayerInteract.cs(36,34): error CS1061: 'InputManager' does not contain a definition for 'OnFoot' and no accessible extension method 'OnFoot' accepting a first argument of type 'InputManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well can you show us your `InputManager` code then?

Answer (score 0):

I had the SAMMMMEEE problem but I know the fix know (Thanks to a friend) all you have to do is to go into your InputManager and turn onFoot to public. In your Player Interact in the very last if function chane the Uppercase Onfoot to Lowercase onFoot. That's what works for me!

Comment: I ment to say Change. Hope that helps though. DONT GIVE UP :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Input Actions you have to press Save Asset at the top of the window.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem but it worked for me when I did change "**O**nFoot" to "**o**nFoot"(as Naeto3452 said) and if change "private" to "public" in InputManager.cs "private PlayerInput.OnFootActions onFoot;" it might help